# nomad: summary has failed=1 and complete=1 at the same time

Tags: nomad

I've run one dispatched job that exits with code 0. But in job summary I see job has `failed` and `completed` at the same time.

```
# nomad status run-packaging-a8173887-b37f-4273-9ad7-8691654bb5d4/dispatch-1503480991-c1bd3b3f
ID            = run-packaging-a8173887-b37f-4273-9ad7-8691654bb5d4/dispatch-1503480991-c1bd3b3f
Name          = run-packaging-a8173887-b37f-4273-9ad7-8691654bb5d4/dispatch-1503480991-c1bd3b3f
Submit Date   = 08/23/17 09:36:31 UTC
Type          = batch
Priority      = 50
Datacenters   = mhd
Status        = dead
Periodic      = false
Parameterized = false

Summary
Task Group  Queued  Starting  Running  Failed  Complete  Lost
system      0       0         0        1       1         0

Allocations
ID        Node ID   Task Group  Version  Desired  Status    Created At
aec6e219  769ff893  system      0        run      complete  08/23/17 09:36:31 UTC
```

And alloc-status:

```
# nomad alloc-status aec6e219

Recent Events:
Time                   Type        Description
08/23/17 09:37:16 UTC  Terminated  Exit Code: 0
08/23/17 09:36:31 UTC  Started     Task started by client
08/23/17 09:36:31 UTC  Task Setup  Building Task Directory
08/23/17 09:36:31 UTC  Received    Task received by client
```

How to explain this result? How can it possible and why `failed` appeared on succesful task?

Answer (score 0):

It failed once and completed on a second try.

Comment: good try) but there is alloc log where task started only once.